# Angular 11 stuck on "Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)"

Tags: angular

Everything is working fine yesterday, today when start my angular 11 project, I got stock on "/ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)..." have anyone experienced this, or can give me advice on how to move forward.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC?

Comment: Can you edit and add the build error logs ?

Comment: @OwenKelvin, yah i have already

Comment: @HDJEMAI can you elabore, on how can i do this? currently there are no error on my terminal, if that would make some sense

Comment: it's weird that you don't  have any logs, try adding `--verbose` when building.

Comment: @HDJEMAI i have added verbose flag, there is still nothing on my terminal excepth the "Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)..."

Comment: I've just tested that in my app, I got many logs

Comment: i cant get passed on the building phase, i get stock, i have added an image on my post if that would help

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` and then `ng build --verbose`

Comment: @HDJEMAI, i really appreciate your response, i did "npm cache clean --force" already, its stil thesame, also it is my second time having this issue, so i created another project and turns out this issue still occur, so thats why i decided to post this here!!! also i did "enforce stricter type checking and stricter bundle budgets in the workspace" enable this when i create this project could this ne the reason?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Have same issue when trying to run ng test

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just keep in mind that you might have to do some changes in your `angular.json` file.

1. In `architect > build > configuration` section add:

```
"development": {
  "buildOptimizer": false,
  "optimization": false,
  "vendorChunk": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": true
},
```

2. In `architect > build`

```
"defaultConfiguration": "production"
```

3. In `architect > serve > configurations` section add:

```
 "development": {
   "browserTarget": "{{PROJECT_NAME}}:build:development"
  }
```

*Note*: You should put the actual project name in the place of {{PROJECT_NAME}} e.g. `"browserTarget": "my-project:build:development"`

4. In `architect > serve` section add:

```
"defaultConfiguration": "development"
```

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid target: {"project":"{{PROJECT_NAME}}","target":"build","configuration":"development"}.
How do i set this as a variable?

Comment: I think that it should not be a variable but you should put the actual project name in the place of {{PROJECT_NAME}} e.g. "browserTarget": "my-project:build:development".

Comment: I upgraded from v8 to v12 and gave little thought to configuration changes.  My build time per change was ~40-50 seconds.   Adding the above reduced to 1-2 seconds 

Comment: This one has been frustrating for long enough to finally search how to make all this go away. You are amazing, Mohammed. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure this might work, I'm in the process of trying it out, but could you explain why these steps work, so that we can all figure out the underlining problem..

Comment: The json key for configuration will be "configurations" and not "configuration"

Answer (score 9):

Same error here.

Cause:
There was a .css file wich only contained comments.

Solution:
Delete all comments in this file, or add at least one css class.

Comment: This works but I dont know why, maybe have to do with the copiler algorithm.

Comment: YOU ARE A HERO!

Comment: I'm using PostCSS with Tailwind in Angular 13. Deleting a completely empty scss file also resolved my issue. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: +1. This helped me understand that the issue was related to css/scss files specified in the angular.json. In my case the scss had content, but [included an import to an non-existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73246843/2780791).

Answer (score 1):

is a "breakchange",  node version, you may decrement node version with nvn

1- step install node nvm

looking for: nvm.exe

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

2- change node version to 16.18.0

command: nvm install v16.18.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3bQx.png)

3- swicth you node version:

command: nvm use v16.18.0

Comment: Did you encounter this issue by yourself when using an unsupported Node version? I don't see how this solution is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across the same issue and the cause was the fact that `styles.scss` was **trying to import a file that did not exist at all**.

Unfortunately, `ng serve --verbose` did not help as verbose option does not seem to affect bundle generation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problems with Angular 13.x.x.

Whenever I tried to build my projects with `ng build` the process got stuck in the sealing-phase. After having read this posts here I simply added dummy classes like

```
.dummy {
    color: blue;
}
```

to all empty .css files. And my project contained a lot of them due to the standard generator process of `ng generate component`.

And it worked like a charm. After having done this pretty simple modification, all projects build again properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was Facing the problem in angular 17 version

PS D:\Chart\Mouli\node_modules> ng serve
⠇ Building...
:9:39:
9 │   imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet,Chart],        ╵                                        ~~~~~

Application bundle generation failed. [2.148 seconds]
⠙ Changes detected. Rebuilding...
X [ERROR] TS-992012: Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules. [plugin angular-compiler]

```
src/app/app.component.ts:9:40:
  9 │   imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, Chart],
    ╵                                         ~~~~~
```

Application bundle generation failed. [0.162 seconds]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while running 'ng serve' for my Angular 13 project. Suddenly, after making some changes in the HTML file, the problem arose. However, upon reverting those changes, it started to work again. I added something like this:

```html
<i *ngIf=" !element.isFolder &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'RTF' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'ODP' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'ZIP' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'ODT' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'OTT' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'ODS' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'DOCX' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'DOC' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'JAVA'&&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'JS'  &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'PY'  &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'JSON' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'TXT' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'SVG' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'PPTX' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'PPT' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'XLSX' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'XLS' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'PNG' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'JPEG' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'JPG' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'CSV' &&
                                                extractFileType(element) !== 'PDF'
                                                ">
                                                    <img class="file-folder-class" src="https://res-2.cdn.office.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20231211.002/assets/item-types/32/genericfile.svg" alt="ott">
                                                </i>
```