# Angular 12 Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)

Tags: angular, typescript, build, kendo-ui

I upgraded an Angular 6 project to Angular 12. It was working fine, but now during build it is giving number of warnings, taking long time to compile and not creating the usual build files.

I have already read and made changes to angular.json after reading:
[Angular 11 stuck on "Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537399/angular-11-stuck-on-generating-browser-application-bundles-phase-building)

Here is the output I get after build:

```
    C:\Bitbucket\Web_Apps\Myproject>ng build
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-l10n : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-intl : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-popup : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-label : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-inputs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-buttons : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-excel-export : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-treeview : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @progress/kendo-angular-grid : es2015 as esm2015
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
√ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...7 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .k-input-label:dir(rtl) -> unmatched pseudo-class :dir
  .k-form .k-form-fieldset>.k-hidden+:not(.k-hidden) -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  .k-form>.k-hidden+:not(.k-hidden) -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  .k-rpanel-left+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  .k-rpanel-right+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  .k-chat .k-message-list-content>*+* -> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
  .custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang
√ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files               | Names         |      Size
main.ff7a6ef1023b37b32bb3.js      | main          |   3.73 MB
styles.386eda04d3f0e76d8500.css   | styles        |   1.02 MB
scripts.626bc6e5c188df62db58.js   | scripts       | 169.02 kB
polyfills.82841f8fa27efbbae2b5.js | polyfills     |  80.39 kB
runtime.5db6bc5ec27b96d301d8.js   | runtime       |   1.13 kB

                                  | Initial Total |   4.99 MB

Build at: 2023-03-10T16:49:32.461Z - Hash: 62488792de837eeafa16 - Time: 2112351ms
```

angular.json (after making changes as advised in the post shared above)

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Myproject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "xlsx",
              "rxjs/BehaviorSubject",
              "rxjs/add/observable/throw",
              "rxjs/add/operator/catch",
              "rxjs/Observable",
              "rxjs/operators/map",
              "rxjs/operators/tap"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Myproject:build",
            "serverTarget": "Myproject:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Myproject:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "Myproject:server"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "Myproject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Myproject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                "inject": true
              },
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Myproject-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Myproject:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Myproject",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

and package.json

```
    {
  "name": "Myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prodbuild": "ng build --configuration production --aot=true --output-hashing none",
    "build": "ng build --output-hashing none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.17",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^7.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^4.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^6.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^4.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^6.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.4",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "latest",
    "angular2-notifications": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "dns-packet": "^5.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "npm-check": "^5.9.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.76.0"
  }
}
```